# Angular.js http post request file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I am trying to send files to a server with http post in Angularjs. I've looked up resources and found this one:

https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
        var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

But it doesn't seem to work if you try uploading **any** sort of file up to any server.

Is there anything wrong in that code?

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response or javascript console error as to what do you see when you do this? It will be more helpful.

Comment: It doesn't get any response/error

Comment: You don't need use a FormData object when you're sending a single content-type file. It is required when you're sending multi data forms, i.e. a bunch of different files/objects at once.